# GLSL 150 GL 3.2 black textures

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I can't get my textures to work, all the screen is black.
Here is my code for loading the images, I use lodepng:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> image;
unsigned int error = lodepng::decode(image, w, h, filename);
GLuint texture_id;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

For the rendering I do this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id_from_above); //texture_id were checked, seemed fine
glUniform1i(shader_sampler_loc, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

and my frag shader(trimmed version) is basically doing this:

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, uv_coord);
}
```

The UV-coordinates are fine, the vector from lodepng containes many elements and there is no error returned. To further pin the problem I tried this:

```
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, uv_coord)*0.5 + vec4(1, 1, 1, 1)*0.5f
```

To see if the whole assignment is somehow skipped or the texture in fact black. As a result I still only get a black window. But by removing

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); //x2, and
glUniform1i(sampler_loc, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

all my objects appear gray. I have no clue what is wrong.

BTW: it was working before moving to OpenGL 3.2 (had 2.1 before), and all images are ^2. I use CORE_PROFILE && FORWARD_COMPAT.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

//VBO vertex attributes
attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec2 tex;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 uv_coord;

uniform mat4 mvp_mat;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = mvp_mat * vec4(pos, 1);
    uv_coord = tex;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your vertex shader, from which version of OpenGL did you upgrade?

Comment: That is also not a GLSL 1.50 shader, it is GLSL 1.10. Some lazy GLSL implementations will allow you to use things from GLSL 1.50 without a proper `#version` directive, but this is bad form. It really does not matter here, however, because you are not using anything from GLSL 1.50 and are even using the deprecated texture fetch function: `texture2D (...)` - beginning with GLSL 1.30, you should use the overloaded `texture (...)` function instead.

Comment: Scratch that, with your new edits you have told GL that it is a GLSL 1.50 shader, but you are using GLSL 1.1/1.2 syntax. You should use `in` and `out` instead of `attribute` and `varying` because they are deprecated. While you are at it, replace `attribute vec3 pos` with `in vec4 pos`, then you will not have to write `vec4 (pos, 1)`. All vertex attributes in OpenGL are always 4 dimensional, even if you only give them enough data for 3 dimensions, GL will fill-in **1.0** for W automatically (but this benefit only comes up if you correctly declare it as `vec4` in the first place).

Comment: ok, thx. Online tutorials tend to mix things... I changed everything, but the result is still the same. Though very good to know about the automatic extension, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I kind of solved it, by using OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE it works. Though I would really want to go full 3.2, and find which parts are deprecated...

EDIT:
In my case, I finally found the dumb error, I was using

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, ... //instead of
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ...
```

So I guess the with the old GL I was lucky, and with 3.2 the enum were changed?

Comment: Compatibility profiles are ***full*** 3.2, it is actually the core profile that is only *partial* 3.2. That said, some implementations do not offer "full" 3.2, and *that* is the actual reason you would want to avoid deprecated parts of the API.

Comment: Ok, though osx seems to "force" me to use 3.2 core forward compatible: "NSGL: The targeted version of OS X only supports OpenGL 3.2 and later versions if they are forward-compatible", "NSGL: The targeted version of OS X only supports OpenGL 3.2 and later versions if they use the core profile"

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by some implementations do not offer full 3.2. Mesa and OS X, for instance. You are limited to core profile functionality. On other platforms you can use all of the old API together with OpenGL 4.3 if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, now everything is working as I wished.

Answer (score 4):

```
glUniform1i(shader_sampler_loc, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

. . . should be

```
glUniform1i(shader_sampler_loc, 0);
```

etc.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it. The objects appear all gray because of my shader. But still no textures.. :/

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest try changing the following:

Vertex shader:

- **out** instead of **varying**
- Add layout(location = #) to your attributes and change **attribute** for **in**.

  Make sure, number of locations match the code

Fragment shader: (Assuming since its not complete)

- **in** instead of **varying**
- Add layout(location = #) to your sampler uniform

For the code:

Change

```
glUniform1i(sampler_loc, GL_TEXTURE0)
```

to

```
glUniform1i(sampler_loc, 0)
```

Comment: Ok, did all of that, still the same problem. Though I am not sure which location to use for the samper uniform.

Comment: Any errors or warnings, have you tried use glGetShaderInfoLog?

Comment: No errors or warnings and I am using shaderinfolog.

Comment: Use any, to avoid overlapping try 99 ( layout(location = 99) ) and call glUniform1i(99, 0); instead of glUniform1i(sampler_loc, GL_TEXTURE0); Tell me if that changes anything

Comment: Did you change #version 150 to #version 320 ?

Comment: When I do, the shader cannot be compiled. Is there a GLSL 320?

Comment: btw: is layout(location = #) core GL3.2? On my windows PC it compiles just fine, but on my mac it complains about undeclared identifiers etc...(won't compile)